# Connect remote RabbitMq server

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ server for send message in my Symfony2 application.

I have used OldSoundRabbitMqBundle for this.

After successful installation of RabbitMq server on my application server it is working fine.

But when I install RabbitMQ server on different machine and try to connect it from my application server it is not connecting.

I have given the connection config as follows:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
connections:
    default:
        host:     myrabbitserverIp
        port:     80
        user:     'test'
        password: 'test'
        vhost:    '/'
        lazy:     false
producers:
    messages:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: {name: 'messages', type: direct}
consumers:
    messages:
        connection:       default
        exchange_options: {name: 'messages', type: direct}
        queue_options:    {name: 'messages'}
        callback:         message.amqp_consumer
```

Do I need to change any configuration for RabbitMq server?

Comment: What error do you have? Which platform do you run you application on? Are servers accessible from CLI? Are there any firewall?

Comment: Connection time out error is coming and linux servers are accessible from cli.

Comment: Why the port in `80` amqp default port is 5672 and management plugin located on 15672 (or 55672 prior to 3.0.0)

Comment: I have tried with both Ports as well. :-(

Comment: I would assume you added those users in the remote host? Note that on newer RabbitMQ versions, you can't connect to a remote machine using the guest:guest account